# To extract jar from pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a dependency which is packaged as below

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<groupId>ABC</groupId>
<artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
<type>pom</type>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

How to extract the JAR when the type is POM ?

Please help me , if you are aware of this ...

TIA
Jagan

Comment: What's \*\*pom\*\* supposed to mean? If it's a pom, then there's no jar.

Comment: Yes just pom. <type>pom</type>.

Comment: But as I said, if it's a pom, the artifact is a pom file, not a jar. So I don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a JAR, then you can add it by leaving out the type.

Or there is no JAR, but just a POM, then you cannot add a JAR.